# Ionic change text displayed on ion-select when an option is selected

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ion-select

I don't know if you get the idea. What I want to do is having an ion-select with option, and when user selects, for example, "Albania (+355)" and press OK button, in the select will only be displayed "+355" instead of "Albania (+355)"

add-contact.html

```
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="selected_value" (ionChange)="getCountry(selected_value)" placeholder="País">
        <ion-option [value]="countries" *ngFor="let countries of country">
          {{countries.country_name}} ({{countries.dialling_code}})
        </ion-option>
      </ion-select>
```

add-contact.ts

```
country = [{ "country_code": "AL", "country_name": "Albania","dialling_code": "+355" },
           { "country_code": "DZ", "country_name": "Algeria", "dialling_code":"+213" }];
```

This is what I have:
[name-code-displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BTKl.png)

This is what I try to display: [only-code-displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONRqQ.png)

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @jorghe94 see the marked answer

Comment: Thanks, selectedText works very good!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/select/Select/#input-properties),

`ion-select` has an input property `selectedText` which:

> The text to display instead of the selected option's value.

You can try using `[selectedText]="selected_value.dialing_code"`.

```
 <ion-select [(ngModel)]="selected_value" (ionChange)="getCountry(selected_value)" [selectedText]="selected_value.dialing_code">

        <ion-option [value]="countries" *ngFor="let countries of country">
          {{countries.country_name}} ({{countries.dialing_code}})

        </ion-option>
      </ion-select>
```

Comment: How about if using FormGroup instead of ngModel?

Comment: @nelson6e65 you could if you are using reactive forms.

Answer (score 0):

I could also use the statement of the ionChange event as follows:

```
(ionChange)="getCountry($event)"
```

In this way, the component captures the value that is selected in the select to then process the information you want to display.